# SCNParticleSystem only in Geometry

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'd like to add particle system `rain` (template from X-Code) only to a geometry (Cube, Tube, Cylinder, etc.)

The particle system should only be visible in that geometry. What I have done so far:

```
let tube = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.5, height: 2)
tube.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
tube.firstMaterial?.transparency = 0.4
let nodeTube = SCNNode(geometry: tube)
nodeTube.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -3)

let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "FloatingParticleSystem", inDirectory: nil)
particleSystem?.emitterShape = tube
particleSystem?.birthLocation = .volume

nodeTube.addParticleSystem(particleSystem!)
nodeTube.addChildNode(nodeTube)

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeTube)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok now I got a workaround like:

```
    let tube = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.5, height: 2)
    tube.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    tube.firstMaterial?.transparency = 0.4
    let nodeTube = SCNNode(geometry: tube)
    nodeTube.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -3)
    let bottom = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.6, height: 0.1)
    bottom.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    let bottomNode = SCNNode(geometry: bottom)
    bottomNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -1, 0)
    nodeTube.addChildNode(bottomNode)


    let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "FloatingParticleSystem", inDirectory: nil)
    particleSystem?.birthRate = 100
    particleSystem?.acceleration = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
    particleSystem?.emitterShape = tube
    particleSystem?.isAffectedByGravity = false
    particleSystem?.birthLocation = .surface
    particleSystem?.colliderNodes = [bottomNode]
    particleSystem?.particleDiesOnCollision = true
```

if anyone has a better solution please post here.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you would have to experiment with the settings in the actual ‘ParticleSystem’ file itself e.g. birthrate, etc, in order for it to “fit” within the bounds of the geometry.

Having said this, I tried these tweaks and it seemed to work to a certain extent (on the Rain' one anyway). It’s probably not exactly what your after but I think it should point you in the right direction:

```
particleSystem?.isAffectedByGravity = false
particleSystem?.birthLocation = .surface
```

Hope this might help you...